# filter an array within a collection of objects belonging to an array in Ts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter objects inside an array in order to render them in React with Ts.
I think that when I want to filter I am changing the typing and that gives me an error with typescript, but it allows me to render correctly.
However, I am trying to find out if there is a more efficient way to do this in the code. I want to filter to category genres. The idea is with a query of my path or url compare it with an array of numbers that are ids, each array belongs to a collection of objects within an array.

Something like this would be the API data

```
results = [
    {id:1, title"spiderman", genre_ids:[14,23,3]},
    {id:2, title:"batman", genre_ids:[14,23,3]},
    {id:3, title:"batman 2", genre_ids:[14,23,3]}
  ]
```

My code

```
const df = data?.results.map((item) => {
    const db = item.genre_ids.map(
      (el) => el.toString() === searchParams.get("genre_ids") && item
    );

    return db.filter((el) => el !== false && el);
  });
  if (df === undefined) return;
  const db = df.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), []);
  console.log(db);

  if (searchParams.get("genre_ids"))
    return (
      <>
        {db.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            {toggle ? <ListData item={item} /> : <GridData item={item} />}
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
```

The error says this the property "id" does not exist on type "false | movieApiResult" is not assignable to type "movieResult". Type boolean is not assignable to type "movieApiResult"

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but note that you should never `.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), [])` (it’s [meaningfully slow](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/)). Use `df.flat()` instead.

Comment: That code's pretty confusing. What do you want passed down as the item when mapping to JSX at the end? Is it the original object, eg `{id:1, title"spiderman", genre_ids:[14,23,3]}`, when at least one of the genre_ids matches the search parameter?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, exactly the object that matches the id

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
const df = data?.results.map((item) => {
    const db = item.genre_ids.map(
        (el) => el.toString() === searchParams.get("genre_ids") && item
    );

    return db.filter((el) => el !== false && el);
});
```

`.map` does not look like the right tool - the above will produce an array with the same number of elements as the old array, and some of those elements will be `false` (for when the genre doesn't match), and some will be the item in the original array (for when the genre matches). The `.filter` afterwards won't remove TypeScript's detection of `false` possibilities from the returned array. Ditch the `.map` entirely and do it in a single `.filter`.

The `if (df === undefined) return;` is superfluous because even when there are no results, an empty array isn't undefined.

`const db = df.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), []);`  doesn't do anything useful either - your `.map` gives you an array of objects. Cloning the array into a new array with the same objects doesn't accomplish anything.

Try:

```
const ids = searchParams.get("genre_ids");
if (!ids || !data?.results) {
    return;
}
const matchingResults = data.results.filter(item => (
    item.genre_ids.includes(Number(ids))
));
return matchingResults.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
        {toggle ? <ListData item={item} /> : <GridData item={item} />}
    </div>
));
```

Having the search parameter named `genre_ids` could well be misleading because, from your logic, it looks like it could only be a single number (eg, 14, or 23, or 3, if it exists at all) - consider renaming the search parameter to `genre_id` to make the resulting code less confusing.